# Why does my home network not show up sometimes in my network listings?

Tags: network, wifi

I'm using a MacBOok Pro, Mac 10.9.5.  It happens frequently that when I wake my Mac from hibernation or simply reboot, my home network is not automatically selected in the "Network" section in my System Preferences.  When I open the "Network Name:" drop down menu, I don't see it in there either.  However, if I click the "Turn Wi-Fi Off" and "Turn Wi-Fi On" one or multiple times, it does eventually appear and eitehr it gets automatically selected or I can select it myself.

My question is, how I can always get it to appear in my network list (assuming I am at home and my router is turned on)?  Note I am always within 15 feet of my router (LinkSys E900).

Comment: Laptop? Desktop? Does the laptop go with you all over & do you connect to other wifi networks on a regular to semi-regular basis?

Comment: To answer that we need to see your Console log, from the wake up moment and then some 50 lines after that. Assuming your Home network is at the top of your networks list. If not move it up.

Comment: WHat is the file path to the console log?  Also, yes, my home network is the first thing on the network list.

Comment: Console app is located in your Utility folder. Open it and then look at all messages. Find the time stamp of the event (wake up), and now copy lines from there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your 10.9.5 and your Router are having problem of identity.

Your 10.9.5 can not find the correct name, or your router is not broadcasting it correctly.

So try changing the name of your Network, and make sure it is moved to the Top of the Network list and choose different Chanel.

Also you could [tell the router that your MAC address belongs to trusted](http://www.linksys.com/gb/support-article?articleNum=135210) ones.

I would not panic but on they web site they skipped 10.9.5 (Mavericks) and call it Yosemite ?

Probably just a stupid typo :)

> Mac OS X 10.7 Lion Mac OS X 10.8 Mountain Lion Mac OS X 10.9 Yosemite

Comment: Making my router recongize the Mac addresses was a brilliant idea and seems to have solved the problem.